# Expected value inequality for $X_n^T$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stopping-times

Let $X_n$ be a bounded random process and let $T$ be a stopping time that is finite almost surely.

Suppose we have the inequality $E(X_n) \geq c$, where $c$ is a constant.

Does it follow that $E(X_n^T) \geq c$ as well?

Here $X_n^T = X_{T \wedge n}$, where $T \wedge n$ is the minimum of $T$ and $n$.

If this is correct, an argument or even a sketch of an argument would be appreciated. If this is incorrect, then a counterexample would be great; also, under what conditions do we have such an inequality for $E(X_n^T)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct.  Let $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 2c) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0) = \frac 12$ and $X_2 = 0$ if $X_1 = 2c$ and $X_2 = 2c$ if $X_1 = 0$.  Then if $T = \inf\{X_n = 0\}$ we have $T \le 2 < \infty$, but $\mathbb{E}[X_2^T] = 0$.

I'm not sure what the tightest conditions to get this inequality are, but $X$ being a supermartingale is certainly sufficient.

Comment: Can you include a sketch of the proof for why supermartingale is sufficient? I thought you needed some boundedness conditions like for the optional stopping theorem, but I am rusty with strochastic processes.

Comment: You included a boundedness assumption in your question.  But it isn't necessary for $\mathbb{E}[X_n^T] \ge \mathbb{E}[X_n]$, only for $\mathbb{E}[X_T] \ge \mathbb{E}[X_0]$ or the like.  Taking $n \wedge T$ removes most of the issues.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $\mathbb{E}[X_T] \le \mathbb{E}[X_0]$

Answer (score 1):

As long as $X_n$ is a supermartingale, meaning $E[X_{n+1}|X_n]\le X_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, then we can conclude that $E[X_n ^T]\ge E[X_n]$. This follows from the general fact that if $X_n$ is a supermartingale and $S$ is a stopping time which is bounded above by $b$ almost surely, then $E[X_S]\ge E[X_b]$. This is proven in *Probability: Theory and Examples* by Durrett, p. $212$, theorem $5.4.1$.

---

Here is a counter-example, Let $X_n$ be an iid sequence of die rolls, $X_n\sim \operatorname{Unif}\{1,\dots,6\}$.

Let $T=\inf\{n:X_n=1$}.

Then $E[X_n]=3.5$, but $E[X_n^T]\approx 1$ when $n$ is large. As $n$ increases, it becomes overwhelmingly likely that a one is rolled at least once in the first $n$ rolls, which case $E[X_n^T]=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean submartingale? The wikipedia article linked suggests that this is true for a submartingale, where c is replaced by E(X_0).

Comment: What I said is correct (according to other answer), but I realized that the proof I had was faulty, so I now do not know why it is true.

Comment: It's true for supermartingales because if $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are two bounded stopping times with $\tau \le \sigma$ a.s. then $\mathbb{E}[X_\sigma] \le \mathbb{E}[X_\tau]$.  Here $\tau = n \wedge T$ and $\sigma = n$.  To @doc's point, it is also true for submartingales because $\mathbb{E}[X_0] \le \mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge n}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \ge \mathbb{E}[X_0]$.

Comment: @doc See my updated answer, it should be complete now.